# How to show help for bundler commands and utilities?

Tags: bundler

`bundle --help` shows a help file that lists commands (i.e. install) and utilities (i.e. show).  How do I view the details on how to use a specific command or utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this through trial and error in the command line:

```
bundle --help show
  Usage:
    bundle show [GEM]

  Options:
        [--paths=List the paths of all gems that are required by your Gemfile.]
        [--no-color=Disable colorization in output]
    -V, [--verbose=Enable verbose output mode]

  Description:
    Show lists the names and versions of all gems that are required by your Gemfile. Calling show with [GEM] will list the exact location of that gem on your machine.
```

So in general, type `bundle --help <command or utility name>`